# How to force IE to download acess file *.MDB?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I tried to make a link for a download of an ACCESS file, it works well on CHROME, FIREFOX .. but not on INTERNET EXPLORER? here is my code, thank's

```
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="down_xls/LIST.mdb" download="LIST.mdb">Download MDB</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`